# How to show the folder name as subdomain using mod_rewrite without actual redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to display the folder name with a default php file name as subdomain without acutally redirecting to the url using .htaccess file.
For Ex: 
If the actual path is http://test.com/view/login.php it must be shown as login.test.com
And if the path is http://test.com/view/container.php it must be shown as view.test.com

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, your examples are doing 2 different things. The first is using the script name as the sub-domain, and the other is using the sub-directory as the sub-domain.  Is this the intention?

Comment: Unclear, xxx/login.php goes to login.xxx and xxx/container.php goes to view.xxx???

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L,QSA]
```